# Arm package: BayesGLM prior

Tags: r, bayesian, generalized-linear-model, prior

I am modelling a logistic binomial response with around 10 (continuous and categorical) explanatory variables.
I would like to model it as a bayesian glm and had a look at the bayesglm function on ARM (package).

The package says: modeling with independent normal, t, or Cauchy prior distribution for the coefficients.

So since I have both categorical and continuous independent variables followed by a binary response variable, would a cauchy or normal distribution be best suitable (I had previously thought a beta would be best since my response variable was binomial)?

A bit lost on what prior scale and prior df to use from the package.
Can I please get some help and advice on what distribution (and values) I should use.

Can I also ask, are there any other ways I can compute a bayesian model to make predictions? thank you

Answer (score 2):

As described in [Bayesian logit model - intuitive explanation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163034/bayesian-logit-model-intuitive-explanation) thread, logistic regression can be described as a linear combination

$$ \eta = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + ... + \beta_k X_k $$

that is passed through the link function $g$:

$$ g(E(Y)) = \eta $$

where the link function is a [logit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/difference-between-logit-and-probit-models) function

$$ E(Y|X,\beta) = p = \text{logit}^{-1}( \eta ) $$

where $X_1,\dots,X_k$ are the predictor variables and $Y$ is a target variable. What we want to estimate is $\beta_0,\beta_1,\dots,\beta_k$ parameters. When using Bayesian approach, for estimating some parameter of interest we start with defining a *prior* that describes out out-of-data knowledge about the parameter, and then use the prior combined with the *likelihood* function (that tells us what the data says about the parameter) to obtain a *posterior* (i.e. estimate of distribution of the parameter). So we choose priors for *parameters* and normal, $t$, Cauchy etc. are perfectly fine *priors* for parameters of regression model or generalized linear model. Beta distribution is inappropriate choice for usual regression model since it would imply that estimated parameters must be bounded in $[0,1]$ interval (you are probably confusing it with [beta-binomial model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180220/how-to-define-prior-for-beta-binomial-a-b-test/186637#186637)).

The parameters for *priors* are different story. You need to choose them based on your out-of-data knowledge about the parameters, so this is a problem-specific choice. If you have no *a priori* knowledge, you can use a [weekly informative prior](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133707/definition-of-weakly-informative-prior/133710#133710), e.g. normal distribution centered at zero with large variance.

Comment: thank you. i understand the prior option now.

but how could I assign a prior to categorical variables?
I also have gender as a variable, is it still ok to use a normal prior for gender?

Comment: @Silver as I wrote, you do not assign priors to variables in here, but to regression parameters. You do not have different kind of regression parameters for different variables.

Comment: sorry, I'm not that clever and my mind just can't seem to get this right.
I think I understand what you mean now: the prior is the guess for the coefficients 
but can you help me with an example:
I know the coefficient for men will be positive/higher (compared to women) and lower for children (compared to adults), how will I set the parameter and prior? or would it be better to sue a non-informative prior since I can't give exact numerical guesses for coefficients?

thank you for the help

Comment: Hi @Tim, do we then, interpret the results the same way as in the classical approach? Example if `genderM` is -0.30, then do we say male patients are 0.74 times *less likely* to be ... as compared to female patients. *or*  male patients have an *odds* of 0.74 times that of female patients in .... Which term is more appropriate?

Comment: @HNSKD the interpretation in [Bayesian](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163034/bayesian-logit-model-intuitive-explanation) and non-Bayesian logistic regression is exactly the same. The difference is that in the Bayesian case you have extra information about the uncertainty of the parameters.